# "Маркетинг-план" - как правильно пишется?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать "маркетинг-план"? Через дефис или раздельно?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: маркетинг-план.

Хотя слово маркетинг по смыслу определяет слово план (является приложением) и находится в препозиции, оно пишется через дефис, так как НЕ СКЛОНЯЕТСЯ. Поэтому, с точки зрения грамматики,  это сложное слово, а не словосочетание.

Можно применить и более простое правило: при отсутствии соединительной гласной два существительных, обозначающих один предмет, пишутся через дефис, кроме исключений вида "старик сторож, красавица-невеста".